# Как переписать код, чтобы при итерации добавлялся +1 балл?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

```
`calc.onclick = function() {
    var myform = this.form,
        chbx = myform['mytest'],
        chnm = myform['myname'],
        sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < chbx.length; i++) {
        if (chbx[i].checked && (chbx[i].value == 'Дождь' || chbx[i].value == 'Снег'))
            sum++;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < chnm.length; i++)
        if (chnm[i].checked && (chnm[i].value == 'Ваня'))
            sum++;
    if (myform.street.value == 'Московская') sum++;

    myform.result.value = sum;
    if (sum > 2) {
        document.querySelector('.good-answer').style = "display: block;"
    }
    // if (sum < 2) {
    //     document.querySelector('.bad-answer').style = "display: block;"
    // }
    if (sum < 3 || sum == 2) {
        document.querySelector('.bad-answer').style = "display: block;"
    }
};
```

есть такой код. В условии
if (chbx[i].checked && (chbx[i].value == 'Дождь' || chbx[i].value == 'Снег'))
sum++;
при выполнении условия sum++ добавляется в итоге +2 балла или +1 балл при совпадении 1 из условий. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при совпадении 2 этих слов sum++ добавлялся +1 балл, а если 1 слово совпадает, то не добавляется ничего.

Answer (score -1):

Замените  `||`  на `&&`.

`||` - логическое ИЛИ
`&&` - логическое И

В вашем случае нужно чтобы Дождь И Снег, тогда прибавляет +1,
А сейчас Дождь или Снег

Comment: Менял уже, 0 баллов при правильном ответе получается.  if (chbx[i].checked && (chbx[i].value == 'Дождь' && chbx[i].value == 'Снег'))
            sum++;

Comment: чему равна chbx ?

Comment: Чему бы она ни была равна у вас неверное условие в принципе, оно никогда не выполнится.... ```x=1 and x=2``` примерно тоже самое что ```chbx[i].value == 'Дождь' && chbx[i].value == 'Снег'``` вот примерно так будет нужное поведение ```if (chbx[i].checked && (chbx[i].value == 'Дождь' || chbx[i].value == 'Снег')){ sum++; break};```

Comment: Считает за этот вопрос 1 балл, даже если 1 из условий выполняется. Нужно, чтобы если пользователь выберет 1 ответ из 2 правильных, ему придет 0 баллов. А 1 балл при 2 правильных ответах.